# Data structure for filesystem

Tags: python, tree, filesystems, full-text-search, binary-search-tree

I'm storing / caching the filesystem (filenames only) in memory to be able to do fast research *à la [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com)*. Thus I don't want to use the OS's built-in file search GUI.

I do it with:

```
import os
L = []
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(PATH):
    L.append([root, files])
```

and the result is like this:

```
[['D:\\', ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg']], 
 ...
 ['D:\\Temp12', ['test.txt', 'test2.txt']]]
```

The problem is that doing research takes too much time when `L` will contain millions of elements:

```
query = 'test2' #searching for filename containg this text
for dir in L:
    for f in dir[1]:
        if query in f:
            print '%s found: %s' % (query, os.path.join(dir[0],f))
```

Indeed, this is a very naive search because it requires to browse the whole list to find items.

**How to make the queries faster?**

*Maybe it seems that a list is not the right data structure to do full-text research, is there a tree-like structure?*

Comment: In Python, I think `dictionary` is the thing you are looking for!

Comment: @Acepcs: even if I use a dict `{'D:\\': ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg'], ..., 'D:\\Temp12': ['test.txt', 'test2.txt']}`,  I'll have to iterate over all thousands of key/values to do the search... Can you precise what you had in mind?

Comment: Well exactly a complete algorithm comes in my mind. When you are walking through the directories in your os, try to make a dictionary of file names, each key is a character in the alphabet, and each value is a list of filenames which start with that character, like `{'a':['a3.jpg','ab.jpg'],'b':['banana.gif','bad.jpg']}`, so you can save a lot of time in iteration by building prefix keys. If your data size is really really big, you can build nested prefix dictionary, something like a tree implemented in Python (to a certain degree)

Comment: @Acepcs Nice idea, it looks like building a lookup table / index (like in databases). Aren't their data structures in Python or Python modules that do this internally?

Comment: Sorry I don't know whether there are existed modules or open source packages of senior data structures in Python. But I do know it's common for people to implement a tree structure using `dictionary` or `list` in Python.

Comment: @Acepcs in your example, I would like the query `nan` to return `banana.gif`. Would this mean I should add `banana.gif` to the "index dict" with all these keys: b, ba, ban, anana, nana, na, etc. ?

Comment: No, you don't have to build suffix dict with keys like anana,nana,na,etc. You can just try one-layer prefix dict with keys from 'a' - 'z', even only with one layer prefix, you can speed up your query since you don't have to iterate all values.

Comment: Yes @Acepcs but if I only do an index with prefix letters 'a' - 'z', how can a query `ocola` find `chocolate.jpg` (that will be in 'c' in the index)?

Answer (score 0):

Research in a lists are O(n), Research in dictionaries are amortized O(1). If you don't need to associate values, use sets.

If you want more about this : https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt

In your case, I would use sets. It will make your queries a lot faster.

EDIT :

The way you are doing it, checking every file for a match can't be quicker that way. Even if you use a dict, you would check every filename for a match.

New idea : 
You can create a dict with all filename as keys and root as value for each. This way you can recreate the full path later.

The idea is now to create a tree were each node is a letter and were path between each will made words (filename). It could be difficult to implement and the result may not be faster depending on the way you construct the tree.

You have to remember that you want to check each and every filename and using a list or a dict won't change that. The tree/graph is the only solution I can think of.

Comment: As stated in other comment, even if I use a dict `{'D:\\': ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg'], ..., 'D:\\Temp12': ['test.txt', 'test2.txt']}`,  I'll have to iterate over all thousands of key/values to do the search... Can you give details about how you would implement this with a `dict` or `set`? It appears to me that one would have to iterate on the whole structure to do the search.

Answer (score 0):

Could you consider using a database for this?

SQLite offers :memory: option, which creates your database in memory only.  Of course you can optimise your algorithm and data structure as pointed out in other answers and comments, but databases generally are already very good at this with their indexing, and you would not need to design something similar.

Your table(s) could be either simply one table with fields full_path and filename, and if you indexed it by filename, it would be fast. This would store a lot of redundant information, as every file would have the full path in full_path. A better solution would be to have a table for directories and another for files, and you would just reference directories from files to get the full path of a match.

Just a thought.

Hannu